# NPM dependency for private package of specific version

Tags: github, npm

So i have a private github repo, with a published packages which i use in other projects (All for my company).

Right now i am using the following dependency to target my project.

```
"dependencies": {
   "@myusername/myrepo": "git+https://ghp_mykey:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusername/mypackage.git"
}
```

But this just targets the newest version, can i add anything to the string to target a specific version eg. version 1.2.3?

I have tried to append #1.2.3 to the string but that gives me the error, "error: pathspec '0.0.13' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your releases are prefixed with a `v`. This seems to be the default behaviour on GitHub.

> It’s common practice to prefix your version names with the letter v. Some good tag names might be v1.0 or v2.3.4.

So the correct string would be:

```
git+https://ghp_mykey:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusername/mypackage.git#v1.2.3
```

However, you can also use the `#semver:<semver>` format which may work better.

> <semver> can be any valid semver range or exact version, and npm will look for any tags or refs matching that range in the remote repository

```
git+https://ghp_mykey:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusername/mypackage.git#semver:1.2.3
```

That will also allow you to defile semver ranges if required for your project.

[Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Comment: For you first suggestion i get "error: pathspec 'v0.0.12' did not match any file(s) known to git"

Comment: For the second suggestion i get 
"npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for undefined@0.0.12.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist."

Comment: I also tried "git+https://ghp_mykey:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusername/mypackage.git#semver:=1.2.3" to fit semversion as described in npm documentation but get the same error

Comment: Hmm. does your dependency project use a different format for versioning? also, perhaps try finding all the tags and trying one of them

Comment: I am just following the standard semver and when i look at the packages in my github repo they are just called 1.2.3,1.2.4,1.2.5 and so on, so i don't think anything is different about it.

Comment: Also i found out that if i use the commit id where the package version was created, so "git+https://ghp_mykey:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusername/mypackage.git#8f40696aa94797c2bd0ee8f84e45229c13e56ec5" for example, it works. But that is very hard to keep track of.